# Android Notification Service from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, service, notifications

How do I make a notification service, that will notify user about some new news storeis?

I get news from a `JSON` API (https://newsapi.org/) to my app, and want show user notification if he there are any new stories he hasn't seen.

Comment: Have u checked Push notification concept in android (GCM or FCM)

Comment: @ShanmugapriyaD ,is right .you should use GCM or FCM for push notification along with Broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is easy to create Push notifications in android using FireBase services.Follow my steps here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience go here create your first project in firebase console.

you will get a file downloaded and paste it in your app module and perform instructions provided by the site

create these files in your project.copy and paste 1.https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java  
2.https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

add necessary permissions and gradle plugins.

call this `String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` in Activity class.

To test this by giving required parameters in this site: http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code
Thats beta..
`public class Notification extends Service {
    String datanews;
    String titlenotif;
    String destnotif;
    MyAsynk asynk;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1800000); //тикаем каждые 30 мinute без задержки 1800000

}
//задача для таймера
//Проверяем на новую запись.
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        asynk = new MyAsynk();
        asynk.execute();
        createNotification(getApplicationContext());//пушим уведомление
    }
}
class MyAsynk extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,StringBuilder> {
    @Override
    //работа в бекграунде
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String key = "YOUR_KEY";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL_HERE" + key);
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            uc.connect();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) ch);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return stringBuilder;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder stringBuilder) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("articles");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = object.getString("title");
                String desc = object.getString("description");
                String newsdata = object.getString("publishedAt");
                datanews = newsdata;
                titlenotif = title;
                destnotif = desc;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
}
private void createNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder ncBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    ncBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{500});
    ncBuilder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 3000, 3000);
    ncBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
    ncBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    ncBuilder.setContentTitle(titlenotif + "");
    ncBuilder.setContentText(destnotif + "");
    ncBuilder.setTicker("You have news!");
    ncBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.news_icon);
    ncBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    manager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(),ncBuilder.build());
}
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}`